# How do you align text on different lines in Quarto?

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I'm not having success aligning text on multiple lines in Quarto. This is easy in Microsoft Word. Below is an image of what I want to produce with a Quarto doc rendered to a PDF:

[image]

Here's what I've tried so far in Quarto that has not been successful:

1. Just regular spacing with the space bar to align text.
2. Using the visual mode option: Insert - Special Characters - Non-Breaking Line Space. Aligned text in visual mode, but PDF output is not aligned.
3. Pipe tables attempting to use a variation of the format below from the Quarto help section https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/markdown-basics.html. The problem in the table format, different lines/cells will have different lengths. When attempting this in table form, Quarto keeps attempting to reformat the table.

```
| Right | Left | Default | Center |
|------:|:-----|---------|:------:|
|   12  |  12  |    12   |    12  |
|  123  |  123 |   123   |   123  |
|    1  |    1 |     1   |     1  |
```

I need to be able to align text similar to the image provided for company formatting, but I don't want to use Word because I need to be able to supply results of data analysis and calculations and want to avoid copy/paste.

I'm not familiar with CSS or other potential options, but open to any suggestions on how to align text in Quarto similar to the image.  Thank you.

Comment: Which output format are you targeting? The screenshot looks like Microsoft Word, but you say “rendered to a PDF”, which suggests LaTeX — is this accurate? I’m asking because the layout engines of LaTeX, HTML and (etc.) are all fundamentally different, and unless you just slap a rudimentary table together (which *should* also be possible), you’ll need to use the underlying format’s layout primitives.

Comment: Screenshot is from Microsoft Word. That's the company Word template formatting. My target output from Quarto is rendering to a PDF. I'd also be fine with rendering to Word. I have another Quarto file that I render to Word for similar purposes, but that one doesn't require text alignment. Both Word and PDF if ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pdf output `flextable` works well.

1. Create a `data.frame` with the cells
2. Feed into `flextable()`
3. Remove header and borders
4. Set column `width()`s

````
---
title: "text align"
format: pdf
editor: source
execute:
  echo: false
---

```{r}
library(flextable)
library(tibble)
```

```{r}
df1 <- 
  tribble(~col1, ~col2,
        "Client:", "Multi \n Line \n Text \n Here",
        "Intended Users of The Report:", "One Line Text Here",
        "Third Item:", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
```

```{r}
flextable(df1) |> 
  delete_part("header") |>
  border_remove() |> 
  width(1, 2.1) |> 
  width(2, 4) |> 
  valign(valign = "top")
```
````

Comment: Thank you. This is close. I'm not familiar with flextable. When I run the code you provided, the longer text is centered top to bottom with the left column text. Is there a way to make the first line of the second column the same level with the corresponding 1st column? See the original image I provided in the question for an example. Thanks. This is a start!

Comment: Yes, `valign()` handles the vertical alignment. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. This works for now. I'll research more on flextable() for additional customizable options. Thank you so much!